# Dynamic indexing with specific sum length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dynamic, grouping

I have the following dataframe:

```
    V1
1   100000
2   50000
3   20000
4   30000
5   150000
6   30000
7   20000
8   200000
```

And I need to get the indexes where each time the sum of V1 reaches 50k exactly. So when the value V1 is greater than the limit of 50k, then the index repeats as much times the limit is reached, or if the value V1 is lower than the limit of 50k, groups rows until the limit of 50k is reached or passed. The result would be something like this:

```
    V1
1   100000
1   100000
2   50000
4   30000
5   150000
5   150000
5   150000
7   20000
8   200000
8   200000
8   200000
8   200000
```

I've managed to resolve it with loops but I wonder if it's possible using groupings with pandas functions.

Comment: Was the first row of the input supposed to be `1 100000`?

Comment: The first column are the indexes, so the index of the first row is 1 and the field value is 100000

Comment: You wrote `10000` as the field value for the first row.

Comment: Yes, and thats a mistake, I'm editting

Comment: Why is index 3 omitted from results and index 4 included?

Comment: because at index 3, the value V1 is 20k, then is under 50k and that result is reached when you add the value at index 4, thus, the "grouping" ends at 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cas of the example you give with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':[100000,50000, 20000, 30000, 
                         150000, 30000, 20000, 200000]},
                   index=range(1,9))
```

Of what I understand of "*get the indexes where each time the sum of V1 reaches 50k exactly*", you can do it by creating a column with the number of exactly 50k you have in the sum until each row :

```
ser_50k = (df.V1.cumsum()/50000).astype(int)
df['nb_50'] = (ser_50k - ser_50k.shift()).fillna(ser_50k).astype(int)
```

Now, you can use `stack` to create rows with same index when 50k reach several times:

```
df_join = (df['nb_50'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x)))
                      .stack().reset_index(level=1).drop('level_1',1))
df = df.join(df_join).dropna().drop(['nb_50',0],1)
```

And you get the expected output with your input example.

Problem is, when you have

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'V1':[180000, 20000, 30000, 50000]})
```

My method gives you:

```
       V1
0  180000
0  180000
0  180000
1   20000
3   50000
```

and some errors might happens later, while when you say "*when the value V1 is greater than the limit of 50k, then the index repeats as much times the limit is reached, or if the value V1 is lower than the limit of 50k, groups rows until the limit of 50k is reached or passed*" and I understand you would expect:

```
       V1
0  180000
0  180000
0  180000
2   30000
3   50000
```

In this case, if you don't want to use a loop, for when the number is above 50K, you can do (about the same idea than before):

```
df = df.join(df['V1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x/50000)))
                       .stack().reset_index(level=1).drop('level_1',1)).drop(0,1)
```

But I could not figure out an easy way to do the case where the number is under 50k so your loop `for` might be enough. otherwise, I thought about this way:

```
def nb_group_under(v1):
    global nb_group
    if v1 < 50000:
        return nb_group
    else:
        nb_group += 1
nb_group = 1
df['under_50'] = df['V1'].apply(nb_group_under)
```

then you try to find where 50k is passed in the group created:

```
df['sum_under50'] = (df.groupby('under_50').V1.cumsum()/50000).astype(int)
df['sum_under50'] = df.sum_under50 - (df.groupby('under_50').sum_under50
                                        .shift().fillna(df.sum_under50))
df = (df[(df['sum_under50']>0) | (df['V1'] >= 50000)]
              .drop(['under_50', 'sum_under50'],1))
```

I'm not especially happy about the method for the case under 50, but could not think another way.

Hope it is helpful anyway or gives you some ideas about how to solve your problem without loop

EDIT: for a more general solution, you can create a function returning the number of time 50k is in the value v1 or do a partial sum returning 1 when above 50k, you still need a global variable:

```
def nb_lim_reached (v1, lim_v1):
    global partial_sum
    if v1 >= lim_v1:
        partial_sum = 0
        return pd.np.floor(v1/lim_v1)
    else:
        partial_sum += v1
        if partial_sum >= lim_v1:
            partial_sum -= lim_v1
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Now you can create another column with this function:

```
v1_lim = 50000
partial_sum = 0
df['nb_lim'] = df['V1'].apply(nb_lim_reached, args=( v1_lim,)).astype(int)
```

Now you use the same idea than my reviosu solution with `pd.Series` and `stack`:

```
df = (df.join(df['nb_lim'].apply(lambda nb: pd.Series(range(nb)))
          .stack().reset_index(level=1).drop('level_1',1))
            .dropna().drop(['nb_lim',0],1))
```

Comment: Yes!, thats the issue, this solution is helping me a lot, see, the dataframe I'm currently working on has about 2M rows, and the limit (in this case 50k) could be lower, and the values higher, so the loop could happen a lot and take some time. But thanks for this great solution!

Comment: @ChemaSarmiento yes 2M rows is pretty long for a loop for! check my EDIT, it's a more general solution but don't know how efficient it is on such a large df

Comment: btw, @Ben.T, when you start the example at 180000, the output is right, the method gives what it should  =D